# Static builds with Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator with Qt 4.7.4 in the SDK given out by Nokia  and wish to build an application with no .DLLs or other external libraries (just a standalone .exe) for Windows.

How is this done (please give all possible details as I am new to this)? I understand one can build static apps using Qt only (not Qt creator) but I am using Qt creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**/How-to-statically-link-qt-4/**](http://www.formortals.com/how-to-statically-link-qt-4/) link here will help you achieve, what you are trying to do.

I am aware that answers in the form of embedded links is usually discouraged for the fact that if the source of the link goes down the answer becomes meaningless but in this case the content is too big & enriched to be reproduced in here again.

Comment: This page is useful, after successfully building QT the rest (Qtcreator) is is simple through projects->qt version